# Amazon textract taking a long time with sqs and sns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-textract

I am currently submitting a two page document to Amazon Textract using SNS/SQS rather than polling for retrieving the result.

I find that it is taking 1.5 to 5 minutes, even though I check for a response every 5 seconds.

Is this common? I realize that this method is implied for large volumes of documents, not an immediate response for a user.

Comment: Are you saying that it is faster when you poll for a result, as opposed to using SNS/SQS? Or does it take this long regardless of notification method?

Comment: It is much slower when using sns/sqs. Polling is instantaneous

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still confused. Are you saying that if you poll for a result (eg by calling `get_document_text_detection()`), then the result is generally available very quickly (eg within seconds) -- that is, it returns the JSON with the detected text since the detection job has completed? However, if you wait for a notification via Amazon SNS, then it takes several minutes to receive the notification? If so, what happens if you use the SNS method but call the `get` function while waiting -- are the results available, indicating that the delay is with SNS rather than Textract?